# SQL Select WHERE Column NOT LIKE across multiple lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have got table that is looking like this:

```
+------+-------+-------------+
ID_Loc  Type    Data
+------+-------+-------------+
ABC     RMKS    Hello
ABC     NAM     Joe Smith
ABD     NAM     Peter Hill
ABD     RMKS    Bye Bye
ABD     NAM     Freddy Tall
ABE     NAM     Loran Bennett
ABE     RMKS    Bye Bye
ABF     NAM     Liv Claris
ABF     RMKS    Bye Bye
+------+-------+-------------+
```

And I need to select all ID_Loc WHERE DATA NOT LIKE 'Hello'. When I tried:

```
SELECT distinct ID_loc FROM data_full WHERE DATA NOT LIKE '% Hello'
```

This also selects ID_Loc: 'ABC', which contains 'Hello' in Data.
Also as this is going to affect quite a lot of or rows, would be nice if I can point query to only look at the rows were Type RMKS is used.

I am using MS SQL Server 2008

SQL fiddle address is: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38130/6

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: NOT LIKE '%Hello' take out the space.

Comment: Line ABC is included because your like is '% Hello' with a space while your Data column of ABC is only 'Hello', it the result is correct according to your where statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to select the `ID_Loc` values for which there is no record matching the `'%Hello'` pattern, here's the query to do it:

```
SELECT ID_loc
FROM data_full 
group by ID_Loc
having max(case 
             when DATA LIKE '%Hello' then 1
             else 0
           end) = 0;
```

This is the result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38130/33

If you also need to apply the `Type = 'RMKS'` filter, you can do so in a `WHERE` clause ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38130/35)):

```
SELECT ID_loc
FROM data_full 
where type = 'RMKS'
group by ID_Loc
having max(case 
             when DATA LIKE '%Hello' then 1
             else 0
           end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the space, added the RMKS filter as well.

```
SELECT distinct ID_loc 
FROM data_full 
WHERE Type= 'RMKS'
and DATA NOT LIKE '%Hello'  --'%Hello%' if it can be between other text
```

EDIT:
If `ID_Loc,Type` isn't unique:

```
SELECT distinct ID_loc 
FROM data_full 
WHERE ID_loc NOT IN (SELECT ID_loc FROM  data_full WHERE Type= 'RMKS'
and DATA LIKE '%Hello')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59e9a/8

Comment: Hi, sometimes there are multiple remarks for each line: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59e9a/1 This will work only if there is one line where type = 'RMKS' and DATA 'Hello'. However if there are multiple lines fo RMKS, this does not work

Comment: @Petrik that changes the question and should have been included in the original data OR wording for clarity...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the space and filter by Type

```
SELECT distinct ID_loc 
FROM data_full 
WHERE DATA NOT LIKE '%Hello%' And [TYPE] = 'RMKS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove the space from your `LIKE` clause and secondly, you can use `EXISTS` clauses to filter results that match your criteria:

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38130/46)

**Query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID_loc 
FROM data_full t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID_loc 
              FROM data_full
              WHERE Data LIKE '%Hello' AND ID_loc = t.ID_loc )
      AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT ID_loc 
              FROM data_full
              WHERE Type = 'RMKS' AND ID_loc = t.ID_loc )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38130/46/0)**:

```
| ID_loc |
|--------|
|    ABD |
|    ABE |
|    ABF |
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple Solution with reverse logic, you need a `where not exists`

```
SELECT distinct t.ID_loc FROM data_full t 
where not exists (
   select 1 from data_full t2 
   where t2.ID_loc=t.ID_loc and t2.type='RMKS' and t2.data like '%Hello')
ORDER BY 1;
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38130/54)